# Help with simple MESA OpenGL ES app please?

Tags: windows, opengl-es, mesa

I am trying to get an OpenGL ES demo app to build on Windows with Mesa. I'm confused about the EGL side of things.

When my project links, it can't find eglTerminate() (and other EGL functions).

I've checked for a libEGL.lib file but I don't have one. Do I have to build the src\egl code into a library as well?

Answer (score 1):

Unless something changed recently, I'm not even sure [how you got an ES DLL in the first place](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/mesa-users/2010-November/000133.html).